# Vim - Показывать пробелы и скрыть табы в начале строки

Tags: vim

Всем здравствуйте!

Как можно настроить в vim:

- отображение пробелов только в начале и в конце строки
- показ табов везде, кроме как в начале строки

"set list" не даёт возможности настроить что-нибудь в деталях:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
```

[image: before]

А хочется настроить так:

[image: after]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что требуется. А так, посмотрите whitespace.vim, может что-то напомнит.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Нашёл только whitespace-vim, который подсвечивает красным пробелы в конце строки. Все плагины с похожим названием делают то же.

Comment: Непонятно - зачем? Инструмент предназначен для визуализации того, что происходит в "пустом месте". Для таких дел наверное только свой плагин писать. Даже в голову не приходит, кому такое может понадобиться:)

Answer (score 1):

Для примера

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=darkblue guibg=darkblue                       
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/                                                   
au BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/                                  
au InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#@<!$/                           
au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/                                  
au BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

дальше сами :)